# 100% height using fixed position

Tags: html, css

I'm using position: fixed; to make a div adjusting to different screen sizes. The height is set to 100% in this simplified example to make the div "example" always take up the whole height of the screen. What I want to do is making space both over and under this div and I'm doing so by using `position: fixed;` and `top: 100px; bottom: 100px;`

The problem is that the code only runs `top: 100px;` not both. Is there any way around this problem?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqswf41w/)

HTML

```
<div id="example"></div>
```

Css

```
#example {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 100px; /* This is clearly not working, how do I do this with absolute/fixed position? */
  top: 100px;
}
```

**EDIT**

And if I set the height using this function istead of setting height in css to 100%. How do I do then?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('#example').css('min-height', windowHeight);
  };
  setHeight();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
  });
});
```

Comment: Include your code in the question.

Comment: There is a fiddle in there with my code

Comment: And what happens when that link dies?  The question becomes useless to future readers with the same problem.  Code in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remove the height: 100%. The browser will calculate the distance between the top and bottom value and create the height you need.

new code:

```
#example {
    background-color: #333;
    width: 500px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 100px; /* This is clearly not working, how do I do this with absolute/fixed position? */
    top: 100px; 
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqswf41w/3/)

Comment: Thanks! I made a edit to my question, do you know how to solve that too? :)

Comment: As I said the browser calculates the height value. The height will be the innerheight of the window -topvalue -bottomvalue. So there should be absolutely no need to use javascript here. You can't have 2 different heights at the same time on the same element. Is there something you want to do you are not telling us?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand the box model.  When you say "height: 100%" it means that the height of the element will be the same number of pixels as the containing element with layout.  Setting top:100px will result in moving the box down 100px, but it will not affect the height of the box.  Thus, 100px of the box will overflow the viewport.  This is the same if you specify bottom:100px, except that top 100px of the box will underflow the viewport.

Remove height 100% and the top and bottom instructions will calculate the element height.

```
#example {
    background-color: #333;
    width: 500px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 100px; /* This is clearly not working, how do I do this with absolute/fixed position? */
    top: 100px; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I made an edit to my question, do you know how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this instead of height: 100%, it would be enough;  http://jsfiddle.net/xd2j2shm/1/

```
height: calc(100% - 200px);
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I like RMo's answer more. It is simpler. That being said, they both work.

To clarify, it sounds like you want the div to cover 100% of the height, minus for 100px at the top and 100px at the bottom.

The way to do this is relatively new. You need to use the `calc` value for your `height` property:

```
#example {
    background-color: #333;
    width: 500px;
    height: calc(100% - 200px);
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px; 
}
```

It has wide support in modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: :( :( Thanks for your help anyway! Looks like this solution works too in this  case.